PHP webDav client gives ClientException: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
I want to upload files to NextCloud via PHP on Windows 11. I do not know PHP much but I managed to install sabre/dav via composer
Then I found on the internet simple code sample to list files.
<?php

// installed via - composer require sabre/dav

include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Sabre\DAV\Client;

$settings = array(
    'baseUri' => 'https://cd.wedos.com/remote.php/dav/files/wedos-auth-xxxxxxxx',
    'userName' => 'myEmail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'myPasssword'
);

$client = new Client($settings);

// Upload a file
//$upload_result = $client->request('PUT', 'test-upload.txt', 'This will be written to the txt file');

// List a folder's contents
$folder_content = $client->propFind('path/to/folder', array(
    '{DAV:}getlastmodified',
    '{DAV:}getcontenttype',
), 1);

But I am getting this error
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Sabre\HTTP\ClientException: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in D:\data\projects\erp\php\vendor\sabre\http\lib\Client.php:327

I searched for the solution and it seems to me that I have two options

Disable Certificate Validation - which is not recommended for security reasons. But I have no ideal how to do it anyaway. I would like to actually try because I am going to use webDAV server and PHP client within the same company
install / import certificate

I have no idea what certificate - from cd.wedos.com ?
how and to where to save / import it?



Is there someone that could help me?
UPDATE1
I ran curl -v cd.wedos.com and got these results
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 / [blank] / UNDEF
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=cd.wedos.com
*  start date: Jun  1 15:19:19 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 30 15:19:18 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "cd.wedos.com" matched cert's "cd.wedos.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
*   Certificate level 0: Public key type ? (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Certificate level 1: Public key type ? (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Certificate level 2: Public key type ? (4096/128 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing

So I guess the issue is that PHP cannot see / is not using certificates

As explained in this PHP.Watch article, the issue
is specific to Windows. On other OSes, curl uses the system list of root certificates:

This error is uncommon on Linux, BSD, and macOS systems, but quite common on Windows because there is no
designated file to obtain the root certificates, and the PHP does not ship a root certificate list on its own.

To make it work on Windows, you can follow the instructions contained in the "Download and maintain a cacert.pem file" section:


Download the cacert.pem file

Move the file to a directory accessible by PHP and the web server. For example, to C:/php/cacert.pem.

Edit the php.ini file and modify the curl.cainfo entry to point to the absolute path to the cacert.pem file.

Optionally, restart the Web server (such as Apache) to reload the INI file.



For your target system, which is Debian, it should work out of the box.

It worked. Thank you.. now I am getting different error. ;-) so the original issues was solved.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Sabre\HTTP\ClientHttpException: Method Not Allowed in D:\data\projects\erp\php\vendor\sabre\dav\lib\DAV\Client.php:303
Stack trace:
#0 D:\data\projects\erp\php\vendor\sabre\dav\lib\DAV\Client.php(198): Sabre\DAV\Client->doPropFind()
#1 D:\data\projects\erp\php\webDAV-listFiles.php(20): Sabre\DAV\Client->propFind()

@Radek: This confirms you've solved the Certificate issue and you can now connect to the server. HTTP that is now. Different thing, the HTTP Method is not allowed. Unfortunately the diagnostic message does not contain the method in use, check your app for that and if you have the option, check the access/error logs on the remote side. It's commonly visible in the logs.

@hakre yes, the certificate issue is solved but I do not know how to list files. I created new question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78781742/how-to-list-files-using-php-webdav-client

Run composer installer that also ships with the certificates. Then use the composer diagnose command to verify they are available.
Then retry with the webdav PHP script. It is perhaps already solved then. If not, point to the same configuration for the PHP curl library in use. SabreWebdav also may have an option to point to the certificates, but better do for the curl extension.

I do not know how to accomplish what you suggested. Could you please help me? Check my update1 in the question. Also .. I run current PHP code on Windows 11 on dev environment but later on it will be running on Debian where I have only FTP access. Any chance I can fix that by running PHP code?

On debian you will likely not see that issue. If that is an option for you, I'd suggest you run a virtual server w/ debian close to the remote system so that you can prepare better the FTP transaction, not to mention to develop better. However just a note in this regard: you'll package the distribution package (artifact) locally and never run composer remotely (and this is good, it's a common mistake you can find a plethora of questions on SO about and it's just wrong/cumbersome/waste-of-time/misunderstanding-of-what-a-deployment-is to execute composer remotely). Now looking at your update.

Me thinks that @olivers answer is more on spot and the references he gave look very good to me, so you will likely not get something better in reasonable time. For the follow up error, treat it as one and do a separated diagnosis/trouble-shooting. Don't intermix it with your previous problem. Often it's two steps ahead, one back. My 2 cents.
