How to list files using PHP WebDAV client?
I want to manage files on Nextcloud implementation (cd.wedos.com). I can connect to the server using WinSCP and list, download & upload files. I want to do the same via PHP. Thanks to SO I am able to connect to WebDAV server from my Windows 11 – my dev environment.
I did search on how to use Sabre WebDAV client, but no matter I do I have no idea how to list files.
$folder_content = $client->propfind('', []);

returns
array(5) {
  ["{DAV:}getlastmodified"]=>
  string(29) "Thu, 18 Jul 2024 20:04:28 GMT"
  ["{DAV:}resourcetype"]=>
  object(Sabre\DAV\Xml\Property\ResourceType)#14 (1) {
    ["value":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "{DAV:}collection"
    }
  }
  ["{DAV:}quota-used-bytes"]=>
  string(11) "11825361054"
  ["{DAV:}quota-available-bytes"]=>
  string(13) "3286709522274"
  ["{DAV:}getetag"]=>
  string(15) ""6699754ce26f9""
}

The official Sabre doc is using $client->propfind('collection', array( but the parameter collection gives me error Not found, I used '' instead
$client->propfind('', array(
    '{DAV:}displayname',
    '{DAV:}getcontentlength',
));

That returns
array(1) {
  ["{DAV:}displayname"]=>
  string(47) "wedos-auth-modified-0f5f-4c87-99a2-modified"
}

Which I have no idea what it means.
I found other examples how to use propfind
$folder_content = $client->propfind('', array(
    '{DAV:}getlastmodified',
    '{DAV:}getcontenttype',
 ));

That gives me result
array(1) {
  ["{DAV:}getlastmodified"]=>
  string(29) "Thu, 18 Jul 2024 20:04:28 GMT"
}

In the official documentation there is section called "Discovering WebDAV features". I thought it would help. So I ran it
$features = $client->options();

which returns something that does not help me.
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "extended-mkcol"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "access-control"
  [4]=>
  string(40) "calendarserver-principal-property-search"
  [5]=>
  string(25) "nextcloud-checksum-update"
  [6]=>
  string(18) "nc-calendar-search"
  [7]=>
  string(27) "nc-enable-birthday-calendar"
}

Is there someone who can help me to list all files and directories of a particular folder?

Thanks to Olivier I was able to list using
curl.exe https://cd.wedos.com/remote.php/dav/files/wedos-auth-anonymized/upload   --user username:password   --request PROPFIND

It is not exactly listing directory via Sabre WebDAV client but I guess it will work... I hope I can use cURL for uploading and downloading files too.
I still prefer to use sabre client though

Pass 1 to the depth (3rd) argument of the propfind:
$folder_content = $client->propfind('', [], 1);


WebDAV protocol recognizes three depth levels:

0 – the element only – with PROPFIND that means that only properties of the folder/file are returned
1 – the child elements – that's what you want
infinity – all descendant elements – recursively

